# Always present headers?

Tags: php, http, header

I want to ask if the following headers are always present in a request:

`HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`,
`HTTP_USER_AGENT`,
`REMOTE_ADDR`

I plan on using them to modify sensitive information, but I need to be sure that they will always be present in a `non-threat-intended` request. In other words it will be ok if someone purposely removes any of them, but in order for ordinary users to be able to use my application they will need all 3 of them. Is there any type of standard that requires certain headers to be sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients SHOULD include a user-agent header but it is not required by the HTTP spec.  The Accept-lang header is completely optional.
Remote addr is not even a HTTP header.  I believe it is obtained from the underlying TCP/IP request so I would guess that your framework will always provide that.